# Searching for a substring inside an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, substring

Hi I would like to know if there is a good algorithm to the search of a substring inside an array that is inside another array,

I have something like:

Array(

```
        [0] => Array(
                    [0] => img src="1" /> 
                    [1] => img src="2" alt="" class="logo i-dd-logo" /> 
                    [2] => img src="3" alt="" /> 
                    [3] => img src="4" width="21" height="21" alt="" class="i-twitter-xs" /> 
                    [4] => img src="myTarget" width="21" height="21" alt="" class="i-rss" /> 
                    [5] => <img class="offerimage" id="product-image" src="6" title="" alt=""/> 
                    [6] => <img class="offerimage" id="product-image" src="7" title="" alt=""/> 
                    [7] => <img class="offerimage" id="product-image" src="8" title="" alt=""/> 
                    [8] => <img src="9" width="16" height="16" /> 
    )

[1] => Array(
                    [0] =>  src="1" 
                    [1] =>  src="a" alt="" class="logo i-dd-logo" 
                    [2] =>  src="b" alt="" 
    )
```

)

What I want to do is to know the position of target, for example [0][4] but it's not always the same

What I'm doing now is a while inside another while and checking whith strpos for the substring, but maybe there is a better way to do this, any suggestions?

Thanks for everything

---

Updated code:

> $i=-1;
>
> foreach($img as$outterKey=>$outter) {
>
> ```
>             foreach($outter as $innerKey=>$inner){
>
>       $pos = strpos($img[$outterKey][$innerKey],"myTarget");
>       if (!$pos === false) {
>                   $i=$outterKey;$j=$innerKey;
>                   break 2;
>               }
>             }
>     }
> ```

Comment: No...your solution sounds reasonable if you know it's always 2 layers deep.

Comment: the problem is that for now it's only 2 layers deep but I would like to think in the posibility to scalate this :(

Comment: That array looks like you got it from a Regular Expression parsing HTML. In that case, drop the array and use an HTML parser.

Comment: Hi Gordon, indeed it's from a regex in html, but it isn't mine, I have to use that array =D I recieve the info and have to work with that as a parameter :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm, maybe like:

```
      foreach($outsideArray as $outterKey=>$outter) {
                foreach($outter as $innerKey=>$inner){
                   if(substr_count ($inner , $needle)) {
                         echo $outterKey . " and " . $innerKey;
                    }
                }
        }
```

EDIT: Scalable, I noticed in your comments you want it scalable. How about recursive?

```
function arraySearch($array) {
    foreach($array as $key=>$item){
        if(is_array($item)
            return arraySearch($item);
        elseif(substr_count ($item , $needle)
            return $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: with this solution wouldn't I have to complete the two foreach even if I find the target on the 0,0?

Comment: Two whiles would be the same, I just think foreach is more elegant. A break would get out of the loop if found.

Comment: Also, I saw above you wanted it scalable for levels of arrays in your comments. I posted a recursive solution for unknown subarray levels.

Comment: You should use `strpos()` (`stripos()` to ignore case) instead of `substr_count()` since you only need to know if it's contained and not how many times.

Comment: Thanks, I just add a break and some other modifications, look the update and see what you think (I need it not to ignore case, thats why I'm using strpos()

Answer (score 0):

try this code here you got the complete posistion of your string.
here $find is your substring. $data is your array.

```
$find = "<img src='4' width='21' height='21' alt=' class='i-twitter-xs' />";
 foreach ($data as $out_key => $out_value) 
 {
   if(is_array($out_value))
   {
     if(in_array($find, $out_value))
     {
        $out_pos = array_search($out_value, $data);
        $inn_pos =array_search($find, $out_value);
     }
   }
 }
echo $data[$out_pos][$inn_pos];
```